# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'STATE_UT' not found

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction

[head(mydata)`mydata = Crime
view = (mydata)
str(mydata)
index = sample(2,nrow(mydata),replace = TRUE,prob = c(1,494))
RFM = randomForest (STATE_UT~.,data = Training)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaKnz.png)I'm new to r programming, this error is shown when creating random forest algo for crime prediction..Can anyone help me out??

*ERROR*

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'STATE_UT' not found

Comment: No one can answer that without seeing your data. Can you post the output of head(mydata) please? Thanks.  Also, if possible please try to format your code in a code block, it will be easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is telling you that that there is no column named STATE_UT in Training nor is there a object in the global environment called STATE_UT

```
colnames(Training)
```

will tell you what columns are in the Training object and

```
ls()
```

will tell you what objects are available in the global environment

Comment: Now i edited my code...As you said i tried with colnames(training), the state coloumn is present in that!!